# Adding additional keys to a retrieved collection

Tags: meteor

I retrieve products by doing the following.

```
 Template.Bag.helpers({
    bagged_products: function () {
      var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag") || {};
      var bagged_product_ids = Object.keys(bag);
      var bagged_products = Products.find({_id: {$in: bagged_product_ids}});
      return bagged_products;
    }
  })
```

The dictionary `bag` is an array of `{"product_id": quantity}`. In the template, I also want to show each product's quantity. For example, I would do

```
for each retrieved_product p:
  p.qty = qty
return updated_products
```

The problem is that `bagged_products` is a `LocalCollection.Cursor` type and I don't know how to add a property to this, so I can do the following in a template.

```
        <div class="product-name">{{p_name}}</div>
        <div class="product-price">${{price}}</div>
        <div class="product-qty">{{my_added_qty}}</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transform in your helper:

```
var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag") || {}

var transform = function(product) {
    product.qty = bag[product._id] || 0;
    return product;
}

return Products.find({_id: {$in: bagged_product_ids}}, {transform: transform});
```

Then just use `{{qty}}` or anything else you name it in your #each block where you used `{{my_added_qty}}`

Comment: I think this is a better than initializing a new temporary local collection but I couldn't figure out how to pass in `qty` as a parameter to the transform function. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Where would you get it from to pass it in? i.e if you have `function(product, qty)` where would it get qty from?. At the moment with your temporary collection you can do this instead `product.qty = bag[product._id]` where `var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag") || {}` (defined outside the transform, make sure you don't define this inside the transform to ensure its reactive).

Comment: Nice! In this way I don't need to pass in qty as an argument. I think it's lighter than my solution. Do you see any pitfalls of doing `new Mongo.Collection(null)` ?

Comment: @MaximusS Its a bit more memory/cpu intensive to do that since Mongo.Collection will be reactive and you're inserting data in then requering it. The transform is similar to map and changes documents as they're fetched, the re-query only being when you change the shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up declaring a new local collection before returning the documents.

```
  Template.Bag.helpers({
    bagged_products: function () {
      var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag") || {};
      var tmpBag = new Mongo.Collection(null);
      for (var p_id in bag) {
        var p = Products.findOne({_id: p_id});
        p.qty = bag[p_id];
        tmpBag.insert(p);
      }
      return tmpBag.find();
    }
  })
```

Comment: did you check [this package?](https://github.com/jeffmitchel/meteor-local-persist)